# How do I set the html document height for this full page background

Tags: html

I've set the html document to min-height:500px; but I need to set it to where I will not have to adjust the position of my footer div, the footer div is currently set to position:absolute; top:500px;

This my html

```
<head>
  <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
<body>

<div id="center">

<div id="header">
<ul>
<div id="wrapper">
  <li>Cisco</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Products</li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">


</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<ul>
<div id="wrapper">
  <li>Cisco</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Products</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<div id="img">
<img src="http://virtualization.info/en/files/2010/01/RAL_large.png">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my css

```
html
{
min-height:500px;
}
#img
{
position:fixed;
top:-50%;
left:-50%;
height:200%;
width:200%;
}
#center
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
#img img
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
min-height:50%;
min-width:50%;

}
#header 
{
background:white;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
opacity:0.8;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
#header li
{
display:inline;
padding:20px;
}
#content
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:500px;
background:white;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
top:100px;
min-height:300px;
opacity:0.8;
}
#footer
{
clear:both;
background:white;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
top:500px;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
#footer li
{

display:inline;
}
#wrapper
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
width:1024px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give height:100% to html and body

```
html,body
{
min-height:500px;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle. It would be easy to debug jsfiddle.net